# Multiplication of tables in Python

Tags: python

```
i = 1

def printM(n):
    while i <= 6:
        print n*i, '\t',
        i = i + 1
    print
while i <= 6:
    printM(i)
    i = i + 1
```

The result is an error that says referring to `i` before assignment! Any clue what's wrong?

Comment: Looks like you haven't defined `i` inside the function. Add an `i=1` in the first line of your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take care the variable localization. Usually in functions/methods it's better not to use global vars. Better way is to use it as argument oder local var inside the function/method

Example for your code:

```
def printM(n):
    i = 0
    while i <= 6:
        print n*i, '\t',
        i += 1
    print

i = 0
while i <= 6:
    printM(i)
    i = i + 1
```

Output:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   
0   2   4   6   8   10  12  
0   3   6   9   12  15  18  
0   4   8   12  16  20  24  
0   5   10  15  20  25  30  
0   6   12  18  24  30  36
```

Answer (score 0):

The `i` in the `printM` function is local to that function.  If you mean the global `i`, you should declare it so:

```
def printM(n):
    global i
    ...
```

Note that using global state in your functions is not a maintainable pattern; it would be better to add it as an argument:

```
def printM(i, n):
   ...
```

Comment: That will help a bit, but wont be totally correct as you also increment the local var "i", so the "external" while loop wont run 6 times

Comment: so after i defined i=1 inside function is it still related to the global i ?

Comment: i = 1

def printM(i,n):
 #   i=1
    while i <= 6:
        print n*i, '\t',
        i = i + 1
    print


while i <= 6:
    printM(i,i)
    i = i + 1

Comment: this gives me a very intereting result. i can see that i inside the function is following the i outside of func

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 1
def printM(n):
    i = 1 (added this line)
    while i <= 6:
        print n*i, '\t',
        i = i + 1
    print

while i <= 6:
    printM(i)
    i = i + 1
```

If you modify your code like this you get this results:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   
2   4   6   8   10  12  
3   6   9   12  15  18  
4   8   12  16  20  24  
5   10  15  20  25  30  
6   12  18  24  30  36
```

i assume that this is what you want.

You did not assign i inside your function. If you want to use the same i which you use later you should use it as a argument of the function which would then looks like this

```
def printM(n, i):
```

Comment: Yes  it is. Thanks! I just do not understand the benefit of bringing i as an argument!